# Unity 3D parallax lag

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, parallax

i try to make a 2D game with Unity for Android (Horizontal Scrolling game) and the background scene is made with 4 different images. The problem is the terrain:
when the speed increase the terrain lag. The game camera it's static, only the images xOffset are changed. FPS: 70.

**BackgroundOffset**

```
public GameObject[] layers;

public float speed;
public float globalSpeed;

private float xOffsetClouds;
private float xOffset_01;
private float xOffset_02;
public float xOffsetTerrain;

Renderer rendererClouds;
Renderer renderer_01;
Renderer renderer_02;
Renderer rendererTerrain;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    rendererClouds = layers[0].GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer_01 = layers[1].GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer_02 = layers[2].GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rendererTerrain = layers[3].GetComponent<Renderer>();

    rendererClouds.sharedMaterial.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(0, 0));
    renderer_01.sharedMaterial.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(0, 0));
    renderer_02.sharedMaterial.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(0, 0));
    rendererTerrain.sharedMaterial.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(0, 0));
}

public void MoveBackground()
{
    xOffsetClouds += Mathf.Repeat(Time.deltaTime * speed, 1);
    xOffset_01 += Mathf.Repeat(Time.deltaTime * speed * 1.3f, 1);
    xOffset_02 += Mathf.Repeat(Time.deltaTime * speed * 2, 1);
    xOffsetTerrain += Mathf.Repeat(Time.deltaTime * speed * globalSpeed, 1);

    rendererClouds.sharedMaterial.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(xOffsetClouds, 0));
    renderer_01.sharedMaterial.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(xOffset_01, 0));
    renderer_02.sharedMaterial.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(xOffset_02, 0));
    rendererTerrain.sharedMaterial.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(xOffsetTerrain, 0));
}
```

**Images Settings:**

```
  Image:      https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VP9k.png
  Material:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDPXr.png
  GameObject: https://i.stack.imgur.com/66JcD.png
```

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Probably because of sharedMaterial : "It is not recommended to modify materials returned by sharedMaterials. If you want to modify the material of a renderer use material instead." https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterials.html Have you tried using the profiler to detect a bottleneck ? Why do you move your terrain instead of the camera ?

Comment: I try to change sharedMaterial with material and in the Unity editor it look better. Now i try it on mobile device. I need to move background becouse the horizontal scrolling is infinity. All generation is procedural and obviusly i can't make an infinity background image.